# How to passing parameter from component.ts to server.ts using ionic angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to get the id from route and use it in my detail_kejadian function to get data from database.
it shows error Undefined index id, and Http failure during parsing for..
What's wrong with it?

This is my component.ts file

```
export class DetailkejadianComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public ks:KejadianService, public route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() { 

    var idkejadian:number=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.detail_Kejadian(idkejadian);
  }

  detailkej = [];

  detail_Kejadian(id){
    this.ks.detailKejadian(id).subscribe(
      (data) => {this.detailkej = data}
    );
  }

}
```

this is the function in my service.ts file

```
  detailKejadian(idkejadian):Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get("http://localhost/matawarga/detailkejadian.php?id=idkejadian");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the argument in your `detailKejadian` method, this string you use in `this.http.get` is always the same.

You could concatenate the value like this:

```
detailKejadian(idkejadian):Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(`http://localhost/matawarga/detailkejadian.php?id=${idkejadian}`);

}
```

Notice the use of backticks (`)  instead of apostrophes or double quotes, and the template literal`${idkejadian}`.

You could also [configure the http request](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server).

Comment: It works, I get the id from the component.ts. But, why my php still can't get the id? Should I use post?

Comment: I PHP you either use $_GET (for http GET) or $_POST (for http POST) or $_REQUEST (for both). Since you are sending the request as GET you should use $_GET.

Comment: That's really helpfull! Thanks a lot